# Sort colors by coordinates of a rectangle

Tags: java, sorting, colors

I am working on a program where I take a photo and find the squares in that photo then determine their RGB values. I am able to get this information successfully but when I find the RGB values and the coordinates where I got them from they come in the order of the contours I found them. My question is how can I take the colors and sort them in a way that I read it from the top left row to the bottom row like a book. Each color has the rectangles coordinates it was taken from, I want to use that to help me order them.

I have an image showing what I want to order.

[image: image I want to order]

When I get the RGB values from the images I print out the color and the coordinates. Here is what it looks like (Notice how they aren't ordered):

```
279,271
R: 106 G: 255 B: 183 

188,270
R: 107 G: 255 B: 180 

371,267
R: 102 G: 255 B: 169 

274,178
R: 75 G: 255 B: 99 

185,179
R: 84 G: 255 B: 103 

369,175
R: 89 G: 255 B: 105 

277,88
R: 96 G: 255 B: 103 

184,85
R: 101 G: 255 B: 110 

370,84
R: 124 G: 255 B: 126
```

My code that I use to get them is here:

I just don't know how I could take the colors and store them sorted.

```
private void getColors(Mat img2read , Rect roi){
    int rAvg = 0 , bAvg = 0, gAvg = 0;
    int rSum = 0, bSum = 0, gSum = 0;

    img2read = new Mat(img2read, roi); //image size of rect (saved contour size and coordinates)
    img2read.convertTo(img2read, CvType.CV_8UC1); //convert to workable type for getting RGB data

    int totalBytes = (int) (img2read.total() * img2read.channels());
    byte buff[] = new byte[totalBytes];
    int channels = img2read.channels();

    img2read.get(0,0,buff);
    int stride = channels * img2read.width();
    for(int i = 0; i < img2read.height();i++){
        for(int x = 0; x < stride; x+= channels){
            int r = unsignedToBytes(buff[(i * stride) + x]);
            int g = unsignedToBytes(buff[(i * stride)+ x + 1]);
            int b = unsignedToBytes(buff[(i * stride)+ x + 2]);

            rSum += r;
            gSum += g;
            bSum += b;

        }
    }
    float[] hsv = new float[3];

    rAvg = (int) (rSum / img2read.total());
    gAvg = (int) (gSum /  img2read.total());
    bAvg = (int) (bSum / img2read.total());


    Color.RGBtoHSB(rAvg, gAvg, bAvg, hsv);

    hsv[2] = 1; //Set to max value

    int rgb = Color.HSBtoRGB(hsv[0], hsv[1], hsv[2]);

    Color brightenedColor = new Color(rgb);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(roi.x + "," + roi.y);
    System.out.printf("R: %s G: %s B: %s \n", brightenedColor.getRed(), brightenedColor.getGreen(), brightenedColor.getBlue());     
    Color colorToAdd = new Color(brightenedColor.getRed(), brightenedColor.getGreen(), brightenedColor.getBlue());
    Point coords = new Point(roi.x, roi.y);
    //colorCoords.put(coords, colorToAdd);
    /*counter++;
    if(counter == 9){
        sortColors(colorCoords);
    }*/
}

int counter = 0;

Map <Point, Color> colorCoords = new TreeMap<>();
Color[] colorArray = new Color[54];
int currentIndex = 0;

//Not really sure what I'm doing here but I don't think it is right.
private void sortColors(Map<Point, Color> colorCoords){

    for(int i = 0; i < colorCoords.size();i++){
    //  colorCoords.get(key)
    }

}
```

Comment: Put those values in to an object, and store them into a `List`...

Comment: Would I need to use getters and setters for the object? @UsagiMiyamoto?

Comment: You could use getters and setters, but is not required....

Comment: That's question I have is how would I order them like I asked in my question, the "book effect" based by the coordinates associated with the average color. @UsagiMiyamoto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put those values in to an object, and store them into a `List`.
To sort, you could add a static `Comparator` field, or make it implement `Comparable` something like this:

```
public class Block implement Comparable<Block> {
   public int x, y;
   public Color color;
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Block other) {
      if (null==other) throw new NullPointerException();
      // implement the logic, like:
      // this will compare X, unless difference in Y is more than EG 10
      return Math.abs(y - other.y) > 10 ? y - other.y : x - other.x;
   }
   public Color getColor() { return color; }
}

public List<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
```

To sort you can use

```
Collections.sort(blocks);
```

### Edited the above comparison to make to your needs...

---

With **Java8**'s **streams** it should be doable to get a sorted array of `Color`s.

But i am not a streams expert. Try something like this:

```
 Color[] colors = blocks.stream().sorted().map(Block::getColor).toArray();
```

For this to work `Block.getColor()` method is needed, see above.

Comment: Alright thanks, it's late now i will try it out in the morning and let you know

Comment: Is there a way I can do this with an Array instead? Just curious @UsagMiyamoto

Comment: Currently right now create that object and the current x and y and set them equal to the objects x and y then add that object to he array. I would have to do it differently right@UsagiMiyamoto

Comment: Because as a result I would want to have a Color [] instead of a List

Answer (score 0):

I would map the coordinates to their corresponding RGB values and then sort first by Y and then by X coordinates to achieve your desired "read like a book" functionality.

Comment: That is what I want to do but don't know how. And I would need both x and y to sort them in a book like functionality

Comment: Well I guess I misunderstood. What are your numbers above the RGB values?

Comment: Those are the coordinates of where the RGB values were taken from. It's the x y of that square.

Comment: So wouldn't sorting by those coordinates still give the same desired effect?

Comment: Sorting the coordinates does give the desired effect. Each coordinate belongs with the image it was from so if I move a square based on its x and y i have to move that color with it.